# Showing the independence of a pair of events $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$

Tags: probability, induction, conditional-probability, independence

This question was taken from [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1178/lectureHandouts/130-independent-random-variables.pdf) article, under the section "Symmetry of independence".

Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of random variables, and denote the event $X_n > X_i$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n-1\}$ with $A_n$. I would like to show that $A_n$ is independent of $A_{n+1}$ and then use the symmetry of independence to demonstrate that $A_{n+1}$ is independent of $A_n$ as well.

As we are dealing with sequences, the natural thing to do is to attempt induction.

#### The base case

As $X_1$ has no preceding elements in the sequence $(X_n)$, $P(A_1) = 1$. Also, as $A_2$ only means that $X_2 > X_1$, we have $P(A_1 \mid A_2) = 1 = P(A_1)$. Therefore the base case is valid.

#### Induction assumption

$$
P(A_n \mid A_{n+1})
= \frac{ P(A_n \cap A_{n+1}) }{ P(A_{n+1}) } = P(A_n)
\quad\text{or}\quad
P(A_{n+1})P(A_{n}) = P(A_{n} \cap A_{n+1})\,.
$$

#### Induction step

By the induction assumption we have $P(A_{n+1}) = P(A_{n} \cap A_{n+1}) / P(A_n)$. Then
\begin{align}
P(A_{n+1} \mid A_{n+2})
&= \frac{ P(A_{n+1} \cap A_{n+2}) }{ P(A_{n+2}) } \\
&= \frac{ P(A_{n+1}) + P( A_{n+2}) - P(A_{n+1} \cup A_{n+2}) }{ P(A_{n+2}) } \\
&= \frac{ \frac{ P(A_{n} \cap A_{n+1}) }{ P(A_n) } + P( A_{n+2}) - P(A_{n+1} \cup A_{n+2}) }{ P(A_{n+2}) } \\
&= \frac{ P(A_{n} \cap A_{n+1}) + P(A_n)P( A_{n+2}) - P(A_n)P(A_{n+1} \cup A_{n+2}) }{ P(A_n) P(A_{n+2}) }\\
&= \cdots \\
&= \frac{ P(A_n \cap A_{n+1} ) }{ P(A_n) } \\
&= P(A_{n+1}) \,.
\end{align}

What might the missing steps denoted by $\cdots$ be, or did I take a completely wrong approach in the first place??

Comment: Are you making any assumptions about the $X_i$? This can obviously not be true for arbitrary $X_i$. Perhaps you forgot to state that the $X_i$ are independently identically distributed?

Comment: @joriki I found the claim in [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1178/lectureHandouts/130-independent-random-variables.pdf) document under the section "Symmetry of Independence", and wanted to try and prove it just like the author suggested. Did I misread something...?

Comment: That seems like a bad text. For one, it uses "eg" where it means "i.e.". I suspect they just forgot to state that the $X_i$ are meant to be independently identically distributed. Consider $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ with the distribution $P(X_1=1,X_2=2,X_3=3)=P(X_1=3,X_2=1,X_3=2)=\frac12$. Then $A_2$ and $A_3$ are clearly not independent; in fact they are identical. (Also, they call the $X_i$ a "sequence of events" but then speak of the values of the $X_i$ as if they were random variables and not events. I suggest you get yourself a better text to learn from :-).

Comment: @joriki It's not that I'm trying to learn from the text. It's more about me trying to come up with a good example of why the symmetry of independence is useful. And if I'm to show an example, I'm of course going to need to be able to prove anything in it that needs proving.